# Nested Anonymous Namespace

Tags: c++, c++17

The following lines are equivalent (starting with c++17):

```
namespace A { namespace B {} }
namespace A::B {}
```

Is there a qualified equivalent for line below?

```
namespace A { namespace {} }
```

*Thank you*

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous namespace (also called unnamed namespace) members occupy global scope and are accessible in all scopes following the declaration in the file. We can access them without any qualification.

If you consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

// named namespace
namespace A {
    // unnamed namespace
    namespace {
        int a;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // initializing an unnamed namespace member
    // you need to use `::` because that unnamed namespace
    // is containing in a named namespace `A`
    A::a = 10;

    // calling the unnamed namespace member
    std::cout << A::a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You must need to use a qualifier `::`, i.e. `A::a`, if you define an unnamed namespace, you'll no longer need to use any qualification as given in the example:

```
// unnamed namespace
namespace {
    int a;
}

int main(void) {
    // simply accessed
    a = 10;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not answer my question. I am looking for a namespace declaration shortcut. I can live without it, but it would be a nice feature.

Comment: @zdf that's what I've mentioned. You wrote in the question - *Is there a qualified equivalent for line below?* - I simply answered: You don't need to use any qualifier to access the members of an anonymous namespace.